# Set 'value' input with AngularJS function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, input, set

I'm kinda noob with AngularJS I have the next div:

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="telController">

        Teléfono: <input type="text" ng-model="telefono.numero" ><br>
        <input type="text"  ng-model="telefono.tras"  > 
        <br>
        El telefono es: {{telefono.telefonoCodificado()}}

    </div>
```

The angularjs function is:

```
function telController($scope) {
            $scope.telefono = {
                numero: "",
                telefonoCodificado: function() {
                    var x;
                    x = $scope.telefono;

                    var parte1;
                    parte1= $scope.telefono.numero;
                    var telCodificado = parte1.substring(0, 3)+"-"+parte1.substring(3, 6)+"-"+parte1.substring(6, 10);

                    return "A) "+x.numero+" <<>> "+ telCodificado;
                },
                tras : function(){
                    var y; 
                    y = $scope.telefono.numero;
                    return y;
                }
            };
        }
```

I want the input with **ng-model='telefono.tras'** get filled with the value that have been typing in the input **ng-model="telefono.numero**" but that doesn´t happend, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New Answer:**

After being updated on the issue, its better to use a `ng-change` to update the other variable.

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

**Old Answer:**

Hi There is no need to write a separate function to copy the `ng-model` (`telefono.numero`) to the variable `telefono.tras`, you can just assign the same variable. Like so.

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

Suppose you need `telefono.tras` populated for some function, then before calling the function, assign the `telefono.numero` value to `telefono.tras`.

So if you want to populate `telefono.tras` you can use the `$watch()` method to do this!

```
$scope.$watch('telefono.numero', function(newValue, oldValue){
    $scope.telefono.tras = newValue;
})
```

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

I hope this answer was useful, please let me know if there are any issues.

**Suggestion:** The input box is allowing numbers and text, to allow only numbers you need to add a directive, refer this [link](https://codepen.io/apuchkov/pen/ILjFr)

Comment: Thank you Naren, I was very helpful, but right now I regret about the way I ask the question. Suppose that I need to set the input with the function: telefonoCodificado?

Comment: @HéctorCapulínPatiño Do you mean like this? [example](https://jsfiddle.net/ynxwmyum/), please confirm the correctness for me to update my answer